# How can I hook into the window.print dialog close event to call a function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How can I hook into the `window.print` dialog close event to call a function?

I am using the jQuery plugin **[Datatables](http://datatables.net/)** and the **[Table tools plugin](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/)** to print data from a web page.

#### Default Behavior

- Format table data to be they only only element visible on the page
- Shows a div that tells the user to click the print button on their browser.
- After the user has printed the user has to press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, which causes the page to look as it did before the print button was clicked.

[image: Example of default datatables]

#### Desired Behavior

- Format the data the same
- Don't show the instructions to click the print button
- Call `window.print();`
- After print dialog closes, cause the page to look as it did before the print button was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

No need for JavaScript, how about this CSS solution?
This should work in all of the browsers, too.

```
@media print
{
 /* Add here any selector for ('root') elements you do not want to be printed. */
 .header, .footer, .floating-print-instructions
 {
  display: none;
 }
}
```

Note that if a selector matches an element that has an explicit `display: block` (and similar) within its `style` attribute and such (or using JavaScript), it will probably still be shown.

Also, I believe some browsers (Internet Explorer?) have `beforeprint` and `afterprint` events, I guess you can listen to them and act accordingly, but this is not really a cross browser implementation and it is a little more complicated than plain CSS.

You can listen to the keyup/keydown events to know that the user pressed Cotrol + P. However, the user may use other ways (menus, toolbar buttons) to print.
Also, in some browsers (Chrome), `window.print()` is partially asynchronous (only `window.close()` calls are run synchronously after it) , so your code might run after it.

Comment: Are you saying don't use the datatables print feature and just use css to hide the things that shouldn't show up on the printout?

Comment: I guess so. I do not know these plugins, I gave a more general solution.

Comment: I like the datatables print feature because the user can still print the page as they see it, but if they click the datatables print button, it will only print the data from the table. I can see how this would help, though not for my needs.

Comment: Well, you can do that, too, I guess. If you hook up to the Datatables print button, you can add a class to `document.body` that will cause the page to show only the tables, otherwise, show everything. You can remove the class by using setImmediate/setTimeout (with a zero timeout or something) to remove that class, though it is not the best solution, yes.